# group unique values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of RestroreModels

if the RestoreCode value exists multiple times in array. Based on unique restore I want to add the TotalCharge value and put the associated model with that RestoreCode in a new array. if the RestoreCode value exist only once put as it is with single model in array.

```
$RestroreModels =  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '3',
      'RestoreCode' => 'FF 0',
      'Model' => 'iPhone 7',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 2015',
      'Model' => 'iPad Mini 2',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4013',
      'Model' => 'iPhone 6',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4013',
      'Model' => 'ipod touch',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'P 21',
      'Model' => 'iPhone 7',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'AL 2015',
      'Model' => 'iPhone 7',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'AL 0',
      'Model' => 'ipod touch',
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '1',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 2015',
      'Model' => 'iPad Mini',
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '1',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4005',
      'Model' => 'iPad Mini',
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '1',
      'RestoreCode' => 'P 21',
      'Model' => 'iPad 5',
    ),
    10 => 
     array (
      'TotalCharge' => '1',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4013',
      'Model' => 'iPhone 7+',
    )
  );
```

i want the result like this

```
$RestroreModels  =  array (

    0 => 
     array (
      'TotalCharge' => '4',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 2015',
      'Model' => array ('iPad Mini 2', 'iPhone 7')
    ),
    1 => 
     array (
      'TotalCharge' => '3',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4013',
      'Model' => array ('iPhone 7+', 'ipod touch', 'iPad Mini 2')
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '3',
      'RestoreCode' => 'P 21',
      'Model' => array ('iPad Mini 2', 'iPhone 7', 'iPad 5')
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'AL 2015',
      'Model' => array ('iPhone 7'), 
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '2',
      'RestoreCode' => 'AL 0',
      'Model' => array ('ipod touch'), 
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'TotalCharge' => '1',
      'RestoreCode' => 'LT 4005',
      'Model' => array ('iPad Mini'), 
    ),
  );
```

I have Tried this so far i am able to get unique values but not sure how to add add TotalCharge and put model related to RestoreCode in $final_array.

```
$final_array = array();
$keys_array = array();

foreach ($RestroreModels as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['RestoreCode'], $keys_array)) {
        $keys_array[$key]       =  $value['RestoreCode'];
        $final_array[$key]      =  $value;
    }

}



var_dump ($final_array);
die();
```

Comment: Please add the code what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the note `if the RestoreCode value exist only once put as it is with single model in array` into account, I think you might use a foreach loop and store the `RestoreCode` of a single array as the key in the result array. Note that the result will differ from your wanted result as the item with a single RestoreCode will also be in the result.

Per iteration check if that key already exists. If if does not, add it and put the value for the Model in a new array.

If it does exist, add the values for `TotalCharge`. To get the unique values for the Models, check if the current array for `Model` already contains it.

If you want to reset the keys, you could use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$res = [];

foreach ($RestroreModels as $item) {
    if (isset($res[$item["RestoreCode"]])) {
        if (!in_array($item["Model"], $res[$item["RestoreCode"]]["Model"], true)) {
            $res[$item["RestoreCode"]]["Model"][] = $item["Model"];
        }
        $res[$item["RestoreCode"]]["TotalCharge"] += $item["TotalCharge"];

    } else {
        $item["Model"] = [$item["Model"]];
        $res[$item["RestoreCode"]] = $item;
    }
}

print_r(array_values($res));
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ia0jA)